# ajax call to Joomla 3 returns Internal Server Error 500

Tags: php, ajax, joomla, controller

I ported my own working component from Joomla 1.5 to 3.4. Made trivial changes like JComponent to JComponentLegacy, JView to JViewLegacy, etc. However, the ajax call returns Error 500 now, and I could not find any additional info to troubleshoot it.

Here is Php generated view:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function ($) {
    $(document).on('click', 'input[type=submit]', function () {
        var value = $('input[name=data]').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'index.php',
            data: 'option=com_mystatus&task=getstatus&data=' + value + '&format=raw&controller=ajax.raw',
            success: function (response) {
            $('.status').html(response.replace(/\"/g, ""));
        }
    });
    return false;
});
})(jQuery)
</script>
<form>
    <span class="contentheading">The Status</span>
    <br /><br />Product key:&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="data" />
    <input type="submit" value="Display Status" />
    <br /><br />
</form>
<div class="status"></div>
```

And here is ajaxraw.php controller:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die( 'Restricted access' );
jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');

class MyStatusControllerajaxraw extends JControllerLegacy
{
    function getstatus()
    {
        echo 'this is OK'; // this was simplified for test purposes
    }
}
?>
```

Can you see what is causing the error 500? If not, could you recommend how to debug this issue?

Comment: `console.log(value);`? what does browser return by visiting `index.php?option=com_mystatus&task=getstatus&data=5&format=raw&controller=ajax.raw`  (with a sample value to data 5 for example)? And please what made you choose a GET for a form submit?

Comment: Yes, I tried console.log, and also tried to turn on debugging in php.ini, but it seems that function getstatus() is not even hit. I suspect that jimport, or smth else is incompatible with Joomla 3, as this was working with 1.5.

Comment: the browser returns:

    View not found [name, type, prefix]: mystatus, raw, mystatusView

Comment: But it exists:
class MyStatusViewMyStatus extends JViewLegacy
in file components/com_mystatus/views/mystatus/view.html.php.

Is it possible that the file cannot be found because a component folder structure changed btw Joomla 1.5 and 3.4?

Answer (score 0):

Use this for your data string:

```
'option=com_mystatus&task=ajax.getstatus&data=' + value + '&format=raw'
```

Specifically, you'll want to call the ajax.getstatus task which would call the MyStatusControllerAjax controller and its file name should be ajax.raw.php to specify that controller is specifically for the raw format.  Joomla 3.x doesn't use a controller query string to route to a controller, the task string is the primary way of routing to a specific controller.

Comment: Thank you for the info! However, error 500 is still returned. As I mentioned above: 500 View not found [name, type, prefix]: mystatus, raw, mystatusView.
Here is updated request: "http://thesite.com/index.php/component/mystatus/index.php?option=com_mystatus&task=ajax.getstatus&data=blahblah&format=raw".
Previously (in Joomla 1.5) the file name was ajaxraw.php. I tried to rename it to ajax.raw.php, and copied to parent folder, etc. None of the attempts succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

Today I noticed that some other Joomla 3.4 components place customs controllers into "controllers" subfolder. So, I did the same: created the subfolder, and moved ajax.raw.php file there. Also I used URL suggested by Michael: mysite.com/index.php?option=com_mystatus&task=ajax.getstatus&data=7&format=raw. Voila! Everything works now! Thanks a lot to Michael!